# Tailwind in JSX component with props doesn't render in NextJS

Tags: next.js, jsx, rendering, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I thought it would be good to use Tailwind in the JSX component passing some props to handle the Tailwind attribute as I want for different situations.

However, some styles of Tailwind in the JSX component are not rendered.

Let me show an example.

```js
// Flex.jsx
export function Flex({ gap, justify, items, children }) {
  const styles = [
    "flex",
    `gap-${gap || "0"}`,
    `justify-${justify || "center"}`,
    `items-${items || "center"}`,
    "bg-slate-300",
  ].join(" ");

  return <div className={styles}>{children}</div>;
}
```

The Flex component I made above doesn't render in NextJS pages as shown below. For example, I gave a gap value of 4 but there were no gaps between the div tags.

```js
// index.jsx
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Flex gap={"4"} justify={"center"} items={"end"}>
        <div className="bg-green-300">Apple</div>
        <div className="w-32 h-32 bg-yellow-300">Banana</div>
        <div className="w-44 h-44 bg-red-300">Orange</div>
      </Flex>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have checked it in the standard way (i.e. Tailwind inline styles) as shown below. In this case, Tailwind styles were rendered correctly and the changes were reflected immediately when I modified them.

```js
<div className="flex gap-2 justify-center items-end bg-slate-200">
  <div className="bg-green-300">Apple</div>
  <div className="w-32 h-32 bg-yellow-300">Banana</div>
  <div className="w-44 h-44 bg-red-300">Orange</div>
</div>
```

### Question

Would you please tell me why Tailwind in JSX component with props for the handling doesn't render?

##### Current behavior

There are NO gaps between div tags of "Apple", "Banana", and "Orange".

##### Expected behavior

There are gaps between div tags of "Apple", "Banana", and "Orange".

### Reproduction

- **Node.js version:** v18.12.0
- **Reproduction repository:** modified version of [Next.js + Tailwind CSS Example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) for this question

##### Steps

1. Install and start the example

```bash
git clone https://github.com/comverser/with-tailwindcss.git
cd with-tailwindcss
npm install
npm run dev
```

2. Visit localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) documentation:

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:

If you build tailwind classes like this: `gap-${gap || "0"}` Tailwind will not be able to generate those classes in the output css file.

You need to do something like:

```js
// index.jsx
<Flex gapClass={"gap-4"} justifyClass={"justify-center"} itemsClass={"items-end"}>
    <div className="bg-green-300">Apple</div>
    <div className="w-32 h-32 bg-yellow-300">Banana</div>
    <div className="w-44 h-44 bg-red-300">Orange</div>
</Flex>

...

// Flex.jsx
export function Flex({ gapClass, justifyClass, itemsClass, children }) {
    const styles = [
        "flex",
        gapClass || "gap-0",
        justifyClass || "justify-center",
        itemsClass || "items-center",
        "bg-slate-300",
    ].join(" ");

    return <div className={styles}>{children}</div>;
}
```